# Prevent re-render while using custom hooks

Tags: reactjs

I'm experiencing something similar to this:
[Should Custom React Hooks Cause Re-Renders of Dependent Components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56345853/should-custom-react-hooks-cause-re-renders-of-dependent-components)

So, I have something like this:

```
const ComponentA = props => {
  const returnedValue = useMyHook();
}
```

And I know for a fact that `returnedValue` is not changing (prev. `returnedValue` is `===` to the re-rendered `returnedValue`), but the logic inside of the `useMyHook` does cause internal re-renders and as a result, I get a re-render in the `ComponentA` as well.

I do realize that this is intentional behavior, but what are my **best** options here? I have full control over `useMyHook` and `returnedValue`. I tried everything as I see it, caching(with `useMemo` and `useCallback`) inside of `useMyHook` on returned value etc.

**Update**

Just to be more clear about what I'm trying to achieve:

I want to use internal `useState` / `useEffect` etc inside of `useMyHook` and not cause re-render in the `ComponentA`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should Custom React Hooks Cause Re-Renders of Dependent Components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56345853/should-custom-react-hooks-cause-re-renders-of-dependent-components)

Comment: @yanirmidler That is the exact link I used in the first statement of my post, dude :) Thanks for trying to help tho

Comment: Hooks `useState` or `useEffect` always cause re-render. There is no way around. If they hold data upon which the state of the component (visual state) is not dependent, use `useRef`

Answer (score 2):

Try to find out the reason of re-rendering in your hook, probably caused due to a state update. If it is due to updation of states in useEffect then give the states and values as dependency. If your states are updating in a function, do try to call the function in order to invoke.

If these doesn't work, try to use ref. useRef hook can be used to prevent such re-renders as it will provide you with .current values.

It would be better if you remove your useEffect dependencies one by one so that you can know what dependency is causing the error and create a ref for the same.

You can share a codesandbox and I would be happy to help you out with it.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to use internal useState / useEffect etc inside of useMyHook and not cause re-render in the ComponentA

If you want to avoid the renders triggered by `useState()` or `useEffect()` then they are not the right tools.

If you need to hold some mutable state without triggering renders then consider [using `useRef()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables) instead.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60592465/react-usestate-vs-useref) has a nice comparison of the differences between `useState()` and `useRef()`.

Here is a simple example:

```
const ComponentState = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(0);
    
    return (<>
        <button onClick={() => {
            // Will trigger render
            setValue(Math.random());
        }></button>
    </>);
}
```

```
const ComponentRef = () => {
    const valueRef = useRef(0);
    
    return (<>
        <button onClick={() => {
            // Will not trigger render
            valueRef.current = Math.random();
        }></button>
    </>);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was trying to do myself, but I found quickly enough that I need to do a lot of manual work this way, because obviously it's not about simple value, but complex logic using fetch calls and returning objects and functions to the `Component A`, and in such case it's not worth the effort. Unfortunately, of course

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to modularize logic, options here would be to use a global state solution (context will do, you can useMemo() on returned value) or a separate component which will return null and from which you'll setState() state on upper level. A combination of them will also do of course, and I think it can be a bit cleaner then shenanigans with useRef.

Answer (score -1):

there is no way to avoid rerendering, each state change causes the component to be updated, to avoid rerendering I recommend that you generate an auxiliary component that receives said rerendering but this must be as a child of the component