# how to stop rerenders when using a custom hook (maximum depth exceeded)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a react project where I'm trying to separate logic from the UI by moving it to a hook. The hook in question collects paged data from an RTK Query and aggregates it into a state variable `transactions`. If I setTransactions as this aggregate, I don't have a problem, but if I try to change it in any way, I see the component rerender many times, causing a Maximum Depth Exceeded error.

I've distilled this problem down to the bare essentials, removing the UI and all logic not causing the error.

AccountTransactions component:

```js
export default function AccountTransactions() {
    const { transactions, handleMoreTransactionsClick, handleDeleteTransaction } = useTransactions(68);
    console.log('transactions', transactions); // I see this log many times

    return (
        <div></div>
    );
}
```

TransactionsHook custom hook:

```js
export default function useTransactions (accountId) {
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
    const [transactions, setTransactions] = useState([]);

    // load transactions
    const {
        data = [],
        isSuccess,
    } = useGetTransactionsQuery({accountId: accountId, page: page});

    useEffect(() => {
        // setTransactions(transactions); // this doesn't cause rerenders 
        setTransactions([]); // this causes rerenders
    }, [data]);

    return { transactions };
}
```

I'm using `data` as a dependency for the hook's useEffect because `isLoading` remains true after the first page is loaded and subsequent pages won't load. However, some combination of using `data` as a dependency and changing `transactions` triggers a rerender of the component. Even more confusing for me is that in this cut-down code, `transactions` is `[]`, but assigning it a new value of `[]` also causes the rerender.

For completeness, here's the RTK reducer, though I don't believe that's contributing to the problem.

```js
        getTransactions: build.query({
            query: ({accountId, page}) => ({
                url: `/api/transactions/account/${accountId}`,
                method: 'get',
                params: {page}
            }),
            providesTags: (result = [], error, arg) => [
                'Transaction',
                ...result.data.map(({ id }) => ({ type: 'Transaction', id })),
            ],
        }),
```

I'm still getting my head around hooks (and even the rendering process) but I can't see how I've broken any of the rules. Can anyone else spot anything?

Answer (score 1):

`setTransactions(transactions);` doesn't cause render, because previous state `transactions` and new state `transactions` are the same object (same object reference). Therefore hook `useGetTransactionsQuery` called only once.

`setTransactions([])` causes render loop, because `[]` creates new object every time(state changed), which causes render, which causes `useGetTransactionsQuery` hook call, which changes `data` and causes effect.

`setTransactions([])`(state changed) => render => `useGetTransactionsQuery` hook call => `data` changed => effect called => `setTransactions([])`(state changed)

Comment: So how can I set `transactions` (there's more information to include than what is directly provided by `data`) to include `data` without causing endless rerenders? It's no use to me as an empty array.

Comment: I'm still confused why the rerender occurs. I've changed state for many variables in the past and it only causes rerenders to components that depend on it (usually child components). Here, I'm not even trying to render `transactions` and it's not a prop for the component. The component asks for a value and then for some reason while the hook is calculating the value, it rerenders. AccountTransactions doesn't even know what value `transactions` has when the rerender occurs.

Comment: Does your data have id for each record? It is probably not the best practices, but you can try using concatenated ids as effect dependecy. As an experiment at least. Something like `useEffect(() => {}, [data.map(({ id }) => id).join('-')])`

Comment: so something that checks for changes in data before triggering the useEffect? I'll give that a go. Thanks. I'd still like to understand why the component is rerendering in the first place.

Comment: In react changing the state of a component causes it to render

Comment: And state inside custom hook is basically the same thing as the state of component. There is an explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/56346042/14763011

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257289/discussion-between-batemir-karuev-and-maganthro).

Answer (score 1):

`setTransactions(transactions);` does cause a render loop because `transactions` is a stable reference to a value, whereas `setTransactions([]);` the value is a new object reference each time and this fails React's `object.is` reconciliation process.

In any case though, you'd pretty much never want or need to enqueue a React state update to its own current value, there's really no point.

It is actually a general React anti-pattern to duplicate the fetched `data` into the local `transactions` state, the problem being you've now two "sources of truth" that need to be kept synchronized.

The `useTransactions` hook should just return `data` directly.

Example:

```js
export default function useTransactions(accountId) {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

  // load transactions
  const {
    data: transactions = [],
    isSuccess,
  } = useGetTransactionsQuery({ accountId, page });

  ...

  return {
    transactions,

    // And presumably these handlers, and anything else the hook returns
    handleMoreTransactionsClick,
    handleDeleteTransaction,
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, but you've missed 2 important points in my question. First, I'm using the hook to separate the logic from the UI. Your suggested hook does nothing more than the standard RTK query so there's no point in having the hook at all - all logic is still with the UI. Second, `data` is paged, and needs to be added to the existing list (each page needs the context of the prior data). Showing only one part of the data won't work in my use case. I'm not sure I understand 'enque a React state update to its own current value', but I this is one of those 'pretty much never' cases.

Comment: Yes, having two sources of truth isn't ideal, but RTK query doesn't handle aggregated paging well, so I'm stuck with managing it myself.

Comment: @maganthro The `useGetTransactionsQuery` and API slice separates the fetching/query logic from the UI. Your `useTransactions` hook is coupling it. RTK-Query can certainly handle [pagination](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/pagination) just fine, and if you need to aggregate all the paged data you can have your queries [manually update the cache](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/manual-cache-updates). This is all easily accomplishable outside your UI code.

Comment: @maganthro When I have a bit of time I can see about creating a demo, if you would like one to see how this works.

Comment: I would definitely be interested in seeing how a more advanced query works, especially if it can also manage the summing of all earlier values. My current paging solution is based on the `pagination` link you referenced, but that doesn't aggregate data. I have to do that manually, and while doing so, I also keep a running total of values for display.

Comment: I understand what you mean that the api slice separates the fetching logic from the UI, but I apply a lot more logic on the raw data before I display it. I would like the same code to be used in different projects with different UIs and it's those pieces I want to separate.

Comment: @maganthro Well, we can only address & answer given the information you provide in your post, none of these extra use cases/constraints/etc are specified in the post. That said, you can apply additional logic on the cached data also via the query hook on the UI side with the [selectFromResult](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/queries#selecting-data-from-a-query-result) property of the options arg. You can encapsulate all this "additional logic" in a custom hook for sure, but the point still remains that you shouldn't then also duplicate the result into a local state.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257302/discussion-between-maganthro-and-drew-reese).